# MATLAB video/image processing surveillance

Tags: matlab, image-processing, tracking, video-processing, matlab-cvst

How to detect dropped object in MATLAb. I am trying to design a MATLAB based algorithm to detect dropping of  small objects by another object . i have decided the area algorithm but it seems there is some error . please suggest something and provide code if possible.

Comment: This is not an acceptable question on SO. Please at least try a little.

Comment: The question is way too broad. But this example may be of help: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html